User Discord Avatar Not Displaying in Django Template
Django Python OAuth Discord getting an avatar from the Discord API, please help me how to do this.
On the index.html page, the user's avatar is not displaying in the <div class="auth"> block. I have tried several methods, but none worked. I can't find information on how to properly load the user's avatar.
Here is the relevant code:
index.html:
<div class="auth">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="user-info">
            <img style="z-index: 9099;" src="{{ user.avatar }}" alt="User Avatar">
            <p>{{ user.avatar }}</p>
            <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
            <a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}" class="logout-button">Logout</a>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="auth-buttons">
            <a href="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="login-button">Login</a>
            <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="register-button">Register</a>
            <a href="{% provider_login_url 'discord' method='GET' process='connect' %}" class="discord-button">Login with Discord</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    discord_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    discord_avatar_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_discord_avatar_url(self):
        if self.discord_user_id and self.discord_avatar_hash:
            return f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{self.discord_user_id}/{self.discord_avatar_hash}.png"
        return None

views.py:
def index(request):
    return render(request, "html/index.html")

urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from meow_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('terms/', views.terms, name='terms'),
    path('politika/', views.politika, name='politika'),
    path('events/', views.events, name='events'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('meow_app.urls')),
]

Django Python OAuth Discord getting an avatar from the Discord API, please help me how to do this.
Add signals.py, change models.py so that the user's avatar appears, but nothing happens

<img style="z-index: 9099;" src="{{ user.get_discord_avatar_url }}" alt="User Avatar">?
